# Nginx redirect to node-red dashboard gives me double /uiui/

Tags: nginx, node-red

I want to show my node-red dashboard with a duckdns link.
I've putted this code in my config file of Nginx.

But if i test my set-up, i get:

Cannot GET /uiui/

When i remove the /ui it gives me the right link with the /ui correctly.
But it is not configurd like that...
How can i find out why there is a extra ui/ ?
If i put http://my-ip:my-port/ui/ get: Cannot GET /ui/ui/
If i put http://my-ip:my-port/halloui get: Cannot GET /halloui/

System: Rock-pi 4 with docker/portainer
I have a Nginx docker and i have also Openmediavault installed...
and i have read that Nginx is also used by Openmediavault...
is it becaus i run 2 instances? And is there any conflict with the config files?

How can i find the problem?

allready re-installed Nginx and Openmediavault

```html
### Based on alpine defaults
# https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/nginx/nginx.conf?h=3.15-stable
user abc;
# Set number of worker processes automatically based on number of CPU cores.
include /config/nginx/worker_processes.conf;
# Enables the use of JIT for regular expressions to speed-up their processing.
pcre_jit on;
# Configures default error logger.
error_log /config/log/nginx/error.log;
# Includes files with directives to load dynamic modules.
include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;
# Include files with config snippets into the root context.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
events {
    # The maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by
    # a worker process.
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    # Includes mapping of file name extensions to MIME types of responses
    # and defines the default type.
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    # Name servers used to resolve names of upstream servers into addresses.
    # It's also needed when using tcpsocket and udpsocket in Lua modules.
    #resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 2606:4700:4700::1111 2606:4700:4700::1001;
    include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
    # Don't tell nginx version to the clients. Default is 'on'.
    server_tokens off;
    # Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request, as
    # indicated by the request header Content-Length. If the stated content
    # length is greater than this size, then the client receives the HTTP
    # error code 413. Set to 0 to disable. Default is '1m'.
    client_max_body_size 0;
    # Sendfile copies data between one FD and other from within the kernel,
    # which is more efficient than read() + write(). Default is off.
    sendfile on;
    # Causes nginx to attempt to send its HTTP response head in one packet,
    # instead of using partial frames. Default is 'off'.
    tcp_nopush on;
    # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
    # included in server blocks where listen 443 is defined
    # Enable gzipping of responses.
    #gzip on;
    # Set the Vary HTTP header as defined in the RFC 2616. Default is 'off'.
    gzip_vary on;
    # Helper variable for proxying websockets.
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mylink.duckdns.org;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://myip:1880/ui/ ;
    }
    }
    # Sets the path, format, and configuration for a buffered log write.
    access_log /config/log/nginx/access.log;
    # Includes virtual hosts configs.
    include /etc/nginx/http.d/*.conf;
    include /config/nginx/site-confs/*.conf;
}
daemon off;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

Comment: it is in the nginx.conf file. a put the whole config snippet in my question.

Comment: in meanwhile my system has crashed :-).
So i did a new installation of Debian and portainer on my Rock Pi 4 SE.
BUT, even when there was nothing running, my link where always redirected to duckdns.org/ui    . I think it is server-side related... but i can't find a setting page ons duckdns...
I did once try a node-red duckdns node and i think i have to look in that to resolve it. In meanwhile i created a now duckdns link, and everything works fine.

Comment: Thats the whole point. I don’t want to add something after the / from the www. But redirected to /ui automatically. But now it’s broken and need to fix the duckdns…

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to edit the `settings.js` mounted in `/data/settings.js` in the Node-RED container.

First change the `httpAdminRoot` to something like `/editor` this will mean that the Node-RED editor will move from `http://ip-address:1880/` to `http://ip-address:1880/editor`

Then change the `ui: { path: 'ui' }` to `ui: { path : '/' }` which should remove the `/ui` from the dashboard path.

You can then use :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my-link.duckdns.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-ip:my-port/ ;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be a good solution indeed.
But now i need to be sure why this is happening... it looks like there is a fault somewhere in one of the configs i think. Because now i get redirected to the UI link, but it is nog configured like that.

Comment: Did what you suggested. Works much easier. And learned something about the configuration possibilities. In meanwhile everything crashed (after updating Openmediavault and Nginx).

Comment: Did install of Debian again on my rock pi 4 SE. New docker, new node-red and also found NginX Manager container where it is much easier to manage proxy server.